# Why bitcoin faucets pay different amount depending on user's location?

Tags: faucets

I have noticed that faucets like moon faucets, bonusbitcoin and bitfun pay a lot more satoshi for the same amount of time and bonus depending on location.
A person in US earns around 7 times more than a person in India.
Any reason for such a huge difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some faucets may pay based upon the ad revenue that they will earn from the user. A site may earn more ad revenue from someone visiting from the US because their advertisers are willing to pay more for US traffic than Indian traffic. Thus the faucet owner may opt to pay US visitors more in proportion to the additional ad revenue which they are bringing.